# No response from Arducam OV5640 camera module

Tags: camera, vhdl, sensors, fpga, zynq

I am working on a project involving cameras using a Zynq FPGA on a Digilent Zybo board.  I can successfully get a response from an OV7670 by configuring it via SCCB.  Even without configuration the OV7670 provides a PCLK and drives the data pins as long as I provide it an appropriate XCLK signal.  I have recently bought an Arducam OV5640 module.  The documentation that I have read so far about this module suggests that I can still use 3.3V logic.  I get no response from this module when providing a 12-25MHz XCLK signal.  Can someone point me in the right direction and make me aware of what I may be doing wrong?  Is it really 3.3V logic or should it be less?  Is there some power-up sequence that I am not aware of that I should be doing differently than the OV7670?

Any help will be much appreciated.  I am really stuck and it is well known that Omnivisions documentation is far from complete.

Comment: Voting to close this question, it's not a programming question and appears to belong on Electrical Engineering StackExchange See [No response from Arducam OV5640 camera module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248591/no-response-from-arducam-ov5640-camera-module).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this Arducam module but the OV5640 image sensor uses 1.8V for I2C. I assume the module does the conversion but you should make sure of this.
Your best bet is to do what I did, which is to research the OV5640 in detail and then research the module in detail.

I'll attach my notes, it may be helpful to you but even if you can't use them, it gives you an example of how to bring everything together.[image]